# QAbstractTableModel from Socket

Tags: qt, qabstracttablemodel

I am trying to get my head wrapped around the QAbstractTableModel and am not quite sure how to get started.   I have the following:
   Reading from a socket, It returns a bunch of lines of strings - terminated with EOL..

I dump all of this into a QStringList. I then need to parse this line by line to
   create my rows and columns of my table. I have written a function to parse the list,
   but not sure if I should pass a pointer to the ModelIndex, and build the table , and if
    so what does that look like...
    Cant really sseem to find an example that is building a dynamic table with multiple
    rows and columns that are of unknown size at creation.
A bit confused about how to do this.

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is QAbstractItemModel's [canFetchMore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [fetchMore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) methods. These are meant for dynamic models (of unknown/large size), and help to inform your attached views that more data is available to display. An example of using this method can be found in the [fetchmore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-fetchmore.html) example in the Qt examples.

Much more complex examples (using threads, for instance) can be found throughout the Qt codebase:

- [QFileSystemModel](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/widgets/dialogs/qfilesystemmodel.h)
- [QSqlQueryModel](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.h)
- [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/corelib/itemmodels/qsortfilterproxymodel.h)

Comment: Yeah, I see how this would be helpful if fetching more random records, I however am doing something that isn't that dynamic. I am reading a bunch of string into a QStringList, and I want to build a 6 column table off of each line of text. Since there is quotes in the text I needed to write a funtion to parse the text into fields(Columns) - which I did. Then how to put that into a table and display the model. Dont need to edit it at all just display...